# MYSQL JOIN sorted join, lost

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

**tbl1**:

| id | name | tid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some text | 1 |

**tbl2**:

| tid | level | related_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 6 |

I want to join tbl1 to tbl2 on tbl1.tid = tbl2.tid, I only want one row joined from tbl2 based on the level for example I want the least level first that is level 1 row joined

**joined table**

| id | name | tid | level | related_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some text | 1 | 1 | 4 |

is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: good give it a try

Comment: Why is this tagged for both *mysql* and *postgresql*? And the `mysqli` is only relevant if you have a PHP program.

Comment: I am using PHP. I can use both mysql and postgres

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `CTE`, noting that `row_number()` function is supported only with `MySQL v8.0` and higher.

```
with cte as
(select 
tbl1.id, tbl1.name, tbl2.tid, tbl2.level_, tbl2.related_id
 , row_number() over (partition by tbl1.id order by level_) as rn
from tbl1 inner join tbl2
on tbl1.tid=tbl2.tid)
select cte.id, cte.name, cte.tid, cte.level_, cte.related_id
from cte where rn=1
```

See the result from [db-fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4YQtDXCPaHZ2zpRCEnnjbw/0)

In comments, I suggested to use the `min(level) over (partition by tid)` function in a `where clause`, but this will not give the required results unless the `level` field is unique, where it's not the case as I guess.